# BufferedImage only Appears when Window is Minimized and Re-Maximized

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage

I'm currently writing an application using Java Swing. So far, the application is simple, it creates a window (`JFrame`) that fills the screen. This `JFrame` has a main `JPanel`, and in that `JPanel` is a `JLabel` for the title and a `JLabel` that I'm loading a `BufferedImage` into. When I run the program, the `JLabel` containing the title shows up, but the `JLabel` containing the image I'm loading in doesn't appear. However, when I hit the "minimize" button on the window, and then maximize the window again, the image appears as it should. Why isn't the image showing up when the program is opened? My code is shown below:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1400;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 800;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public MainWindow() {
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        this.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        this.mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        this.add(mainPanel);
        setupObjectInsertPanel();
    }

    private void setupObjectInsertPanel() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("TileSets");
        mainPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        try{
            BufferedImage tilesetImage = ImageIO.read(new File(...)); // path ommitted
            JLabel tilesetIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tilesetImage));
            mainPanel.add(tilesetIcon, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            System.out.println("Loaded tileset into panel");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open tileset");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The try statement always succeeds, and the success message is printed when the program starts up, but the image isn't showing up until the window is minimized/re-maximized. Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: You need to move this.setVisible(true); to the end of the code block.  Set visible true once everything is set.

Comment: Minimize and restore forces a repaint.

Comment: or call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container after you've updated it